# Pointer to an object still points to the first memory allocation

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object, dynamic-memory-allocation

Given this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class samp
{
    int i;
public:
    samp(int i)
    {
        this->i=i;
    }

    void show()
    {
        cout << "Sample" <<" "<<i <<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    samp* ptr ;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        ptr = new samp(i);
        ptr->show();
        delete ptr;
    }
    ptr->show();
    return 0;
}
```

`ptr` is defined to point at 10 different `samp` type objects. I know that after deleting it, there is no guarantee of getting the desired output. But running this program again and again shows that `ptr` is still pointing to the very first object and the last `ptr->show()` (statement before `return` statement) gives:

```
Sample 0
```

But at the last time in the loop, `ptr` was pointing to the 10th object, so it is supposed to be that the last `ptr->show()` (statement before `return statement`) should give:

```
Sample 9
```

Why it is still giving `Sample 0` instead of `Sample 9`?

Comment: You're trying to reason about undefined behavior. It's pointless. The behaviour can change with the change of compilation flags, compiler, day of week, etc.

Comment: " I know that after deleting it there is no guarantee of getting desired output " ... so, what is the question ?

Comment: In this case, `i` is likely getting zeroed out, which makes you *think* the last `show()` is acting on the memory of the the first object, when it really is not. If `show()` were to print out the value of its `this` pointer instead, you would see that the last `show()` is acting on the memory of the last object, not the first object.  It is undefined behavior for the last `show()` to print the value of `i` since `this` is not pointing at a valid object, but it is not undefined behavior to print the value of `this` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the last ptr->show() (statement before return statement) gives:
>
> Sample 0

This happens because you have deleted the pointer before and therefore, as you say, *there is no guarantee of getting the desired output*. You should not use the last ptr->show().

Comment: Assign `nullptr` instead of delete? What?

Comment: In this case it avoids the unexpected result

Comment: How about memory leak?

Comment: When the program reaches the end the pointer gets automatically deleted, so as for this case is concerned there really isn't any problem. Using `nullptr` is a good idea when you are going to be using that pointer in the future, and using `delete` when you are not going to be using it anymore.

Comment: "When the program reaches the end the pointer gets automatically deleted, so as for this case is concerned there really isn't any problem." this statement is utterly wrong. As well as one that this is a good idea.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for pointing that out. It's always good to be corrected.